# How to store a text version controled by git in a database?

Tags: c#, database, libgit2sharp

Task: A version controled large text is to be stored in a database.

Edit: I think the standard solution in a database would be one row per text version or, for example, using CHANGETABLE (MS SQL Server). But that would be a waste of space.

Problem: So far I have not been able to find any usable information on processing the data with libgit2sharp in memory. But I'm new to libgit2sharp.

Question: Can you use libgit2sharp for this? I don't want temporary copying the files to disk, so that it should be done in memory.

In detail, one would need the following functions:

```
public class VersionInformation()
{
   public string CommitId { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
   public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

// dbField is the complete git repository from the database (in this case one file, one branch)

IEnumerable <VersionInformation> GetVersionInformations (string dbField)
{ ??? }

string GetText (string dbField, string commitId)
{ ??? }

string UpdateDbField (string dbField, string description, string author, string newText)
{ ??? }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `extensive version controled text` what does it mean?

Comment: It means that it would be a waste of space to create one record per version.

Comment: In my opinion it would be the most elegant solution, provided that libgit2sharp allows an easy implementation.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you mean, to be honest. Yes, libgit2sharp provides details of commits... is that all you're looking for? What do you mean by "create one record per version" - what is a "record" here? What is `dbField`? Please try reading your question as if you were coming to it with no information other than what's in the question... how well would you understand the problem?

Comment: I hope the revision helps better understand my question.